# How to get the user logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with trying to set the value to the user that logged in to the website. This is what I have so far but I'm getting this error 
Error   CS0200  Property or indexer 'Employee.getName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only. What changes would I make to set the user that logged in the view

**Employee Model**

```
 public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Employee Number")]
    public int employeeNum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Department")]
    public string department { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {


            return string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName);
        }
    }


    public string getName
    {
        get {
            IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO();
            dbObj.connectionString = "Server=tw-testdb-04;Database=TWCL_OPERATIONS;uid=sa;password=P@ssw0rd";
            var emp= dbObj.getEmployee(employeeNum);
            return emp;
        }
    }


}
```

}

**Controller**

```
private Requisition getRequisition
    {
        get
        {
            Requisition requisition = (Requisition)Session["Requisition"];
            if (requisition == null)
            {
                requisition = new Requisition();
                Session["Requisition"] = requisition;
            }
            return requisition;

        }

    }

 public ActionResult RequisitionItem()
    {
        //Session.Clear();
        //Set the document number and type to autoamtic values
        IssueDAO dbData = new IssueDAO();
        getRequisition.reqDate= DateTime.Now;
        getRequisition.reqNumber= string.Concat("RN", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssms"));
        getRequisition.count = 0;
        getRequisition.inventory_account = 5520;
        getRequisition.employeeDetails.getName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;


        getRequisition.item = new Item();

        return View(getRequisition);
    }
```

Comment: Just as the error states, `getName` is read-only.  Look at your implementation for `getName`.  It fetches a value from a database and returns that value.  What exactly do you expect to happen by assigning something to `getName`?  What specifically are you trying to do?  Did you mean to set `firstName` or `lastName` instead?

Comment: The user that logged on to the website, I want to store that name to a label on the view

Comment: Use a view model for the view and set the FullName property of that.

Comment: @Shyju give an example of what it would like in the view

Comment: create a view model (simple POCO ) with properties needed for the view. If you need to show FullName. Keep a property for that `public string FullName { set;get;}` and have your view strongly typed to the view model. In your get action, create an object of the view model, assign the property values and send that to the view. Keep the class simple and lean

Comment: already have this  public string Name
    {
        get
        {


            return string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName);
        }
    }
 so I need to add a setter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property or indexer 'Employee.getName' cannot be assigned to -- it is
>   read only.

The error is self explanatory. In your `Employee` class, you have defined `getName` with only `get` accessor method for this property. That means, the value of it can only read by some other code. You are trying to set the value to this property and hence the compiler is complaining about it.

If you want the value of this property to be settable by some other code, you should have a [`set` access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/set) on this property.

IMHO, you should keep your view models lean and simple. There should not be any data access code to get data inside a view model properties ( that is mixing 2 concerns ,UI and Data access together!)

I suggest you have a settable and gettable property in your view model to pass the logged in user name

```
public class Employee
{
   // Your other properties
   public string LoggedInUserName { set;get;}
}
```

Now you can set this as needed

```
var emp=new Employee();
emp.LoggedInUserName = "Any username value here";
```

or

```
emp.LoggedInUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```